# Set value depending on drop down list selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

So I am trying NOT to use VBA here.

I have a drop down list to select one out of 3 possible shifts: Early, Late, Night.

[image]

Depending on the selection I want to fill out the Time column in a table below in intervals of 15 minutes. Starting at 6:00 for Early, 14:00 for Late, and 22:00 for Night.

[image: When I change the shift to Night as in this example I expect the time column to update automatically starting with 22:00]

The drop list is in merged cell D3:J3 and the Time column is in range C8:C40.

I tried with an `Index()` and `Match()` combination and gave me a Value Error. I also tried with nesting `If()` but always returned the value 0.

In another topic I would like the Workbook to always open as a new unsaved workbook to avoid overwriting files.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51264836/edit) your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please - specifically an example of your data input and an expected output. Be it screenshot, mockup, whatever

Comment: @Rawrplus I edited the question. Sorry I forgot to attach the screenshots at first. I hope those help explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ifs return 0 - how did you write the 6:00 value? because If you have Time format selected for the cell and you assign value 6 as a result of a formula it will give the cell value "6.1.1900  0:00:00" and display 0:00. Because value of 1 represents one day in Excel Time/Date terminology so adding any number without decimals will result in addition of full days without moving from 0:00 time.

But if I use simple IF combination (in cell C8) like this:

```
=IF(D3="Early";6/24;IF(D3="Late";14/24;22/24))
```

it will work correctly and show "6:00" for Early, etc. Then for adding 15 minutes you just put

```
=C8+15/(24*60)
```

and fill down

as for protection against overwriting you can either save it as Template (that way it will always ask where you want to save it even when you use keyboard shorcut to save) or have the file open read-only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! @Pavel_V
The values I typed them myself at first. I tried your proposal and it works for Early. But when I select Late it starts from 22:00 the same as Night. do you know why that could be?

Comment: the only way this can happen is that the value does not match in the second IF and results in 22/24, which means that you dont have "Late" written there in your data validation, but something else - like "Late " with space at the end or something like that. Check the connected cells or the list if you have it written directly in the data validation.

Comment: I checked it and corrected it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: glad I could help. Please mark the question as answered - it makes it easier for people to see what still needs work and less time they spend filtering questions more time they can spend actually answering and helping. Thanks